# VirtualBox VM fails to start because of bridge adapter issue

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I recently updated to Windows 10 version 1903 and I faced some issue for starting my VM on VirtualBox. I've got many errors and I've tried many solutions, but the main problem persists: I can't start my VM.

Here is the latest error I get after trying to start my VM:

```
Interface ('VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter') is not a Bridged Adapter interface (VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR).

Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

But as far as I can tell, I have a bridge adapter up and running:

[image: Network Connections]

I've tried many solutions so far and I'm really tired of searching VirtualBox forum and also uninstalling and reinstalling VirtualBox and restarting my PC, etc.

If any further info is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not the actual answer, however, doing the following, I could start my VM again with bridged network access.

Before update, I was using **VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter** and my VM could start. But after the update, it always failed. After trying many fixes (which actually didn't help a bit), I've decided to change the **name** parameter to another option. After a little trial and error, I could start my VM after selecting **Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver**.